# Hosting Static Website in S3 domain sub diretories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is there any ways or workaround to change the amazon s3 website url from:
example.amazonaws.com
to
s3.amazonaws.com/example

Thank you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think your comment should be an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A path of `s3.amazonaws.com/example` used to be supported (and might still be supported), but there is a plan to deprecate that format in favour of `example.amazonaws.com` because it allows more capabilities within the Amazon S3 infrastructure.

See:

- [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)
- [Update to Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/update-to-amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan/)